# loading page content from .txt file breaks Django template system

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, templates

In my python Google App Engine app, the design for most of my pages is identical, so I created page.html as a basic template.  The content for each individual page is in a .txt file. In my .py script I do this:

```
pageFile = open("content.txt", "r")
pageText = pageFile.read();
pageFile.close()
```

And then this

```
template_values = {
   'full_name': full_name,
   'notification': notification,
   'pageText': pageText
   }

   path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'page.html')
```

When the page is rendered the pageText content does get inserted, but the Django template markup (like {{full_name}}) doesn't get parsed.  Which is my problem.  I suspect the solution to this is to render the html file twice, once to load in the content and once to parse the Django template stuff, but I can't find any resources about how to do this.  Any help appreciated.

EDIT: specific view code

Instruction page

class Instruction(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

```
    checkUser(self)
    checkProfile(self)
    flowControl(self, 0)

    prepareHeader(self)

    global notification

    try:
        notification
    except NameError:
        notification = ""

    pageFile = open("instruction.txt", "r")
    pageText = pageFile.read();
    pageFile.close()

    template_values = {
        'url': url,
        'url_linktext': url_linktext,
        'user': user,
        'pageText': pageText,
        'footerText': footerText,
        'notification': notification
    }

    global instruction, refresh
    instruction = True
    refresh = True

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'instruction.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Comment: What, why don't you use the include template tag ? Can you post your view code ? and templates ?

Comment: hang on, you're blowing my mind.  I don't know about that tag, looking it up.  Thanks for quick reply

Comment: I think I'm using the include template tag, right?  I am doing things as instructed in the GAE docs: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html - all the relevant view code is posted above.  It's just simple django template variables {{like this}} that are not being replaced in my template, because the content that contains them is itself {{one of these}} so they don't get parsed.

Comment: you could also use template inheritance. As to precise "how", i should see your view and template code.

Comment: this include tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include

Comment: yes.  I'm trying it now but I'm pretty sure that's what I need.  Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Django include template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include). Or [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/).

This example includes the contents of the template "foo/bar.html":

```
{% include "foo/bar.html" %}
```

This example includes the contents of the template whose name is contained in the variable template_name:

```
{% include template_name %}
```

Comment: Actually template inheritance might be a better option but without your code I can't rely show you any better than the documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/